# How do I save a black & white picture to a 1-bit image file?

Tags: printing, graphics, image-editing, image-processing

I need a 1-bit image file to print on a laser engraver.

I used to have quite a few graphics applications that could save 1-bit black & white TIFF files. I've owned Macs since 1987. However most of my old apps won't run on current MacOS versions and I just discovered that my current graphics apps (Affinity Photo, Affinity Designer, Acorn, Pixelmator, Pixelmator Pro) won't save 1-bit files. 8-bit grayscale is as close as they get.

I have no problem editing an image so that it only contains black or white pixels. Pixelmator Pro's **Format: Effects: Halftone: Dot Screen** or **Line Screen** effects are great for what I want. It's the underlying file format that I'm having problems getting to with modern software.

I have a workaround. I can save an 8-bit TIFF to a USB thumb drive and open it in Microsoft Paint on the Windows PC attached to the laser cutter and save it as a 1-bit BMP or TIFF file for the laser cutter's software. However the grey haired Mac nerd in me is offended that Windows still has a feature that seems to have vanished from current Mac systems.

Does anyone have suggestions for an app to convert grayscale images to 1-bit TIFF files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org) commandline tool for that. If your image is already Black and White you simply do:

```
convert input_file.tif -depth 1 output_file.tif
```

If you have to make the file B/W just add `-separate -black-threshold 128` (you can adjust the threshold for your needs).

Here's the `exiftool` output for my sample file:

> Bits Per Sample                 : 1

Answer (score 2):

On **macOS** you can use [GNU Image Manipulation Program (GIMP)](https://www.gimp.org) to create 1-bit TIFF files.

With the image opened, go to **Image** > **Mode** > **Indexed** > **(•) Use black and white (1-bit) palette** > **Convert**

Then **File** > **Export As…** > **filename.tiff** > **Export**.

---

<sub>**GIMP** is a free and open source image editor.</sub>